# Memory Leak in C# when compress image

Tags: c#, visual-studio, memory-leaks, imagemagick

I try to compress `ImageSource` with `MagickImage` in memory. But it consumes too much memory. With VS performance tool, every call of this method with consume a lot of memory. It should take 0Mb once it exists, right?

```
internal static System.Windows.Media.ImageSource compressImage(System.Windows.Media.ImageSource ims)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (MemoryStream outS = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    BitmapSource bs = ims as BitmapSource;
                    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                    BitmapFrame bf = BitmapFrame.Create(bs);
                    //encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image1.Source));
                    encoder.Frames.Add(bf);
                    encoder.Save(stream);
                    stream.Flush();

                    try
                    {
                        // Read first frame of gif image
                        using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(stream))
                        {
                            image.Quality = 75;
                            image.Resize(new Percentage(0.65));
                            image.Density = new Density(200, DensityUnit.PixelsPerInch);
                            image.Write(outS);
                        }

                        stream.Close();
                        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                        bitmap.BeginInit();
                        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                        outS.Position = 0;
                        bitmap.StreamSource = outS;
                        //
                        bitmap.EndInit();
                        //bitmap.Freeze();
                        outS.Flush();
                        outS.Close();
                        ims = null;
                        return bitmap;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you use `return image.ToBitmapSource()` instead?

Comment: @dlemstra there is no such method

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Magick.NET? The image should have that method. Maybe you are using the .NET Core version?

Comment: I am using Magick.NET https://magick.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Convert%20image

Answer (score 0):

Since Image is stored in memory pixel by pixel. It will consume much memory depends on its size. 
Specifying its size will reduce much memory.

```
bitmap.DecodePizelWidth = 800;
```